# Getting to know BackGroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted Event is over

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am using background worker class in code as

```
private void bwFilter_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {            
       //Some Code
    }
    private void bwFilter_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {          
       //Some code
    }
```

Now i am calling this events in a button click as

```
btnClick_Click(Object Sender,EventArgs e)
{
      bwFilter.RunWorkerAsync();       
}
```

Now i wanna do something in btnClick only after bwFilter_RunWorkerCompleted is completed. I try the follwing but result in deadlock situation

```
 btnClick_Click(Object Sender,EventArgs e)
{
      bwFilter.RunWorkerAsync();
      While(bwFilter.IsBusy)
      {
          Continue;
      }   
     //Start coding Again Here    
}
```

Comment: Why are you running the worker async if you're just going to block on it? Just make the call in the button click handler.

Comment: @dlev I could not get what u r trying to say on this !!!

Comment: Your bwFilter.IsBusy will become false only when the RunWorkerCompleted Event is fired. Runworker Completed is fired on the UI thread, since its already blocked, your code gets into a deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting for the background worker to finish completely defeats the point of using a worker. And inevitably causes deadlock.

So just don't bother, call bwFilter_DoWork() directly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `RunWorkerCompleted` event, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx

```
bwFilter.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => { ... do something ... };
bwFilter.RunWorkerAsynch();
```

Comment: I am doing the same, i wanna know how to get that compiler is finished with the code written in bwFilter.RunWorkerCompleted event

Comment: The RunWorkerCompleted event hanlder is where you place `//Start coding Again Here `